# Ember.js record.save() is successful, but object has state inflight

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am using a fairly new version of Ember (Ember 3.7.2, Ember Data: 3.7.0)

I create a record in the client (using `store.createRecord()`) and I give it a GUID as the ID.
The record must have an ID in the client because it is not immediately saved to the backend. The user may edit the record before it is saved.

I then save it to the backend with `record.save()` and I use the `JSONAPIAdapter`.
The backend changes the ID to an integer (An autoincrement in the database) and the payload returned from the server includes the newly saved object with this new ID.
The idea is that the ember data framework shall update the record with the new ID from the backend. That does not happen in ember-data 3.7. It did happen in ember-data 3.0.1 before I upgraded to the latest ember version.

The object in the client keeps it GUID and furthermore and it now has the state `"isSaving"=true`.
So, if I later try to delete this object I get this error:

> Attempted to handle event `deleteRecord` on  while in state root.loaded.created.inFlight.

I am using a standard version of the `JSONAPISerializer`.
To be able to give the record an client-side ID, I have subclassed the JSONAPIAdapter to include this mehtod:

```html
generateIdForRecord: function(/* store, record */) {
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
    d = Math.floor(d/16);
    return (c==='x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
  });
  return uuid;
}
```

What should I do to save properly and don't get an error when I try to delete the object?

**NOTE**

I rolled back to ember version 3.0.0 / ember data version 3.0.1. In that version it worked fine. I.e. the ID was updated in the record when the save call returned from the server with the new id.

So there must be a change from ember 3.0.0 to 3.7.0 related to `record.save` and update of ID and state isSaving/saved.

Comment: Don't generate a different ID on the ember side, when you create a new record ember data will assign a temporary random id

Comment: @PatsyIssa, how dows that work? I tried to remove my generateIdForRecord method from my adapter. Then the id became 'null'  and everything broke.

Comment: Why are you generating a GUID at client side?

Comment: @wuarmin, I have updated the questions with more details about why the GUID.

Comment: Good question :).  Check if your backend returns the id as string. JsonApi Id's have to be strings. I have to check your use case on my side, to figure out the issue.

Comment: @wuarmin, yes they are string. This used to work in a previous verison of ember. Now some internals in ember-data has been modified, and now it fails to work.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to save and then delete the record?

Comment: I'm quite sure that ember data does not support mutating IDs. I would bet that it does not even recognize that the record with client-side generated GUID and record returned with server-side generated ID are the same. Did you checked if you end up with two records in the store? One having client-side generated GUID and one server-side generated ID?

Comment: yes, what @jelhan says is correct. In your case, there must be `two records` in your ember store. One with the GUID, another with the id returned from back-end

Comment: `Question`: Do you need to replace your manually created `GUID` with the `ID` that returned from the backend for sure?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you where exploring a bug on the `ember-data`, because it not allows you to change record ids. So I not recommend you to keep generating ids at the frontend and changing it on the backend. You supposed to leave the id `null`, but if it's not working some how, you should take a look on that code.

As a workaround to do a quick and dirty fix you can use the [`unloadRecord()`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.10/classes/DS.Store/methods/unloadRecord?anchor=unloadRecord) instead of the `deleteRecord()`, and it will not send a request to delete this record for the backend.